# I am summing up the volume for each 30m candle, however the total of the volume is close but not matching the real volume of that day

Tags: volume, stock, yfinance

I have written a code where find the volume of the stock and let us say $AAPL.

I was able by using finance to fetch the volume of that stock for a given day and the output was good as what was reported online like Yahoo Finance.

Then I wanted to fetch the volume of each 30m and then sum it up at the end. I was thinking the summing up should equal the total volume of the day or I might be mistaken.

Here is s screenshot of the 30m volumes:

[image: strong text]

I could share my code but they are additional analyzing that you do not have to worry about.

My main reason, I would like to find the total volume as hourly or 30m and at the end add it and the sum should equal whatever is reported to Yahoo Finance.

Here is my code:

```py
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def get_buyer_seller_volumes(ticker, start_date, end_date):
    try:
        stock = yf.Ticker(ticker)
        data = stock.history(interval='30m', start=start_date, end=end_date)
        volume = data['Volume']
        price = data['Close']
        return volume, price
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error retrieving 30-minute volumes and prices for {ticker} from {start_date} to {end_date}: {str(e)}")
        return None, None

# Example usage
ticker = 'AAPL'
start_date = datetime(2023, 5, 11)
end_date = datetime(2023, 5, 12)

volume, price = get_buyer_seller_volumes(ticker, start_date, end_date)
if volume is not None and price is not None:
    print(f"Volume and Price for {ticker} on {start_date} to {end_date} (30-minute candles):\n")

    # Lists to store buyer, seller, and equal price volumes
    buyer_volumes = []
    seller_volumes = []
    equal_price_volumes = []

    for i in range(len(volume)-1):
        current_price = price[i]
        next_price = price[i+1]

        if current_price > next_price:
            buyer_volumes.append(volume[i])
        elif current_price < next_price:
            seller_volumes.append(volume[i])
        else:
            equal_price_volumes.append(volume[i])

        print(f"Time: {volume.index[i]}, Volume: {volume[i]}, Price: {price[i]}")

    total_volume = volume.sum()
    print(f"\nTotal volume: {total_volume}")

    print("\nBuyer Volumes (Price higher than next 30 minutes' price):")
    for buyer_vol in buyer_volumes:
        print(buyer_vol)

    print("\nSeller Volumes (Price lower than next 30 minutes' price):")
    for seller_vol in seller_volumes:
        print(seller_vol)

    print("\nEqual Price Volumes (Price equal to next 30 minutes' price):")
    for equal_price_vol in equal_price_volumes:
        print(equal_price_vol)

    total_buyer_volume = sum(buyer_volumes)
    total_seller_volume = sum(seller_volumes)
    total_equal_price_volume = sum(equal_price_volumes)
    print(f"\nTotal Buyer Volume: {total_buyer_volume}")
    print(f"Total Seller Volume: {total_seller_volume}")
    print(f"Total Equal Price Volume: {total_equal_price_volume}")

    total_all_volumes = total_buyer_volume + total_seller_volume + total_equal_price_volume
    print(f"\nTotal Volume (Buyer + Seller + Equal Price): {total_all_volumes}")
```

Comment: I feel like I am missing a 30m candle that will make the sum correct?